# RecycleView Scroll Issue When Add New Row On Bottom In Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a simple chat application on Android,
in that one is the chat screen,
After loading the initial chat message look like recycle view filled up with conversion and hold at the bottom end scroll position.

Now I have a new message(either I post / from an opponent user) that scrolls to the last message which is fine.

Now I scroll above to see history conversion to read the past messages, and while reading I got a new 2-3 message from my opponent user and my scroll view bounce up down and not hold its scroll position.

Look at the screenshot I attached

After the new message insert, I will update the adapter like

```
    private fun notifyAdapter() {
            try {
                val recyclerViewState = rvGroupChatMessages.layoutManager?.onSaveInstanceState()
                messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                rvGroupChatMessages.layoutManager?.onRestoreInstanceState(recyclerViewState)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
    
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use DiffUtil and also try using the sample code below.

```
recyclerView.post { recyclerView.scrollToPosition(messageAdapter.itemCount - 1) }
```

Comment: Hey @Eyosiyas thanks for the replay, but on that waits scroll on a specific row start position and my row size is any based on chat content size.

Comment: I don't  get what you are saying.

Comment: hey @Eyosiyas, I mean to say like, my recycle view has 100 rows and I read old history like I scroll at 50 rows and reading some content, then you message me at that time if I refer above code its scroll me to 100 positions, but what I refer I continue reading 50 rows where my eye look at without any scroll disturb, same like WhatsApp / skype.

Comment: Get a reference to the current message count and when a new message arrives scroll to the referenced position. I think this might fix it.

Comment: as you look on skype / WhatsApp i need to scroll maintain by not on a specific message, instead, I need exact potision.
because consider my message list is 20+ and each message more then 100 line long.

Answer (score 0):

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvGroupChatMessages"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/cvBottomLayout"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/cvBottomLayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Try this :

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

If you are using ConstraintLayout make sure RecyclerView height is 0dp

Comment: will try this property.